# #define alternative in Swift

Tags: ios, macos, swift

I'm writing UIColor and NSColor extensions. Both share most of the code base. In Objective-C I could write something like this and reuse most of the code:

```
#if (TARGET_IPHONE_SIMULATOR || TARGET_OS_IPHONE)
    #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
    #define CustomColor UIColor
#else
    #import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
    #define CustomColor NSColor
#endif
```

I couldn't find the similar approach to do it in Swift since there is no #define directive in Swift, and it is impossible to use constant in this case.

Comment: Have a look on this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26251801/swift-macro-parameters