# Constant Declaration in swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, swift

I have a constant string defined as

```
#define kNotificationMessage @"It's time to take your %@"
```

In objective C i use

```
[NSString stringWithFormat:kNotificationMessage, medicineString]
```

as the message to the UIAlertView . How do we achieve this in swift

Comment: do you want to use this for uialertview?

Comment: Just use "let" variable

Comment: There are some truly strange and very wrong answers to this question below (including the accepted one).   The equivalent Swift code is `let kNotificationMessage = "Check out what I learned about %@ from Stackoverflow."; let aString = String(format: kNotificationMessage, medicineString)`

Answer (score -2, accepted):

First create a struct

```
struct AStructConstants 
{
    static let sampleString : NSString = NSString(string: "Check out what I learned about %@ from Stackoverflow.")
}

var aString : NSString = NSString(format: AStructConstants.sampleString, "some custom text")
println(aString)
```

Your output would be:

> Check out what I learned about some custom text from Stackoverflow.

Comment: Swift native type is String not NSString. You should use let aString = "whatever". BTW Swift is a type inferred language.

Answer (score 7):

```
let medicineString = "analgesic"
let kNotificationMessage = "It's time to take your %@"

let sentence = String(format: kNotificationMessage, medicineString)

println(sentence) // It's time to take your analgesic"
```

Comment: This is the correct native way to go and in my opinion should be accepted as the correct answer.

Comment: This is the only correct answer in a sea of wrongness.

Answer (score 2):

Please use following code may be solve your problem.

```
let kNotificationMessage:String = "It's time to take your %@"
var modifiedString = NSString(format:kNotificationMessage:String, medicineString) as String
```

Answer (score 1):

```
let msg = "It's time to take your" as String

let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "iOScreator", message:

        "\(msg)" , preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)

    alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Dismiss", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default,handler: nil))

    self.presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

That is how I do alert in Swift. If I didn't understand wrongly and this code is useful for you, I will be glad. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can't. You're going to have to make a function out of it:

```
func notificationMessage(medicineString: String) -> String {
    return "It's time to take your " + medicineString
}
```

For more information, [**this thread**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26251801/swift-macro-parameters) is quite a good read.

Answer (score 0):

You'd better to deal with such constant using `struct`:

```
struct GlobalConstants {
    static let kNotificationMessage = "It's time to take your"
}

println(GlobalConstants.kNotificationMessage)
```